# how to Adjust an image on another image to redirect to another page using html?

Tags: html, user-interface

I am trying to build a page that contains 4 images, there is an absolute one and then each one of the other 3 are relative and redirect to another page, The problem is I want to make them in parallel to each other so I used padding left and top to adjust the img in the position I need but the main problem that I can redirect to any page pressing any place of this padding like the screenshot attached.
I really want to make the img only that can re-direct to another page not all this space.

[image].

I wrote this code

```
<div>
    <img src="./assets/Images/Rectangle 1.png" style="position: absolute;" alt="Main Design" width="100%">
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    <img src="./assets/Images/Account.png" style="position: relative; padding-left: 180px; padding-top: 220px;" alt="Accounts Management">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    <img src="./assets/Images/Bus.png" style="position: relative; padding-left: 150px; padding-top: 220px;"  alt="Bus Management">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    <img src="./assets/Images/Line.png" style="position: relative; padding-left: 150px; padding-top: 220px;" alt="Line Management">
    </a>
```

Any recommendation for how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using margin properties on the anchor element?

I think you can use margin-(top, left, right, bottom) to get into the right position and probably others properties, in this way the only content in the anchor element will be the image and not the padding spaces.

something like:

```
<div>
    <img src="./assets/Images/Rectangle 1.png" style="position: absolute;" alt="Main Design" width="100%">
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" style="position: relative; margin-left: 180px; margin-top: 220px;">
    <img src="./assets/Images/Account.png" style="position: relative;" alt="Accounts Management">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" style="position: relative; margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 220px;">
    <img src="./assets/Images/Bus.png" style="position: relative; "  alt="Bus Management">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" style="position: relative; margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 220px;">
    <img src="./assets/Images/Line.png" style="position: relative;" alt="Line Management">
    </a>
</div>
```